# Zoom popup in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I use the PhotoScroller apple's sample code. I've modified it to have a universal application for displaying image books with paging and zooming scrollview. This works and the behaviour is what I expect.

Now I would like to add a functionality. Here is the description of this function :

When the user double tap on a specific part of a page I'd like that a kind of popover appears on screen containing a zoom focus. Here is a simulation :

http://www.charmissimo.com/temp/simulation.JPG

The focus is a zoom of 1, 2, 3 or 4 depending of where the user doubletapped (note that 1, 2, 3 and 4 are part of the same jpg image).
The user can then swipe left or right to change the focus from 1 to 2 and so on...
The focus disappears when the user doubletaps outside of the focus.

3 other things to mention :
 - The app must be universal (so I can't use popover which is supported only on ipad)
 - The app must be compatible with IOS 4 and IOS 5
 - The position and size of 1, 2, 3 and 4 can change depending of the initial image

Question is : How can I achieve this? What modifications of PhotoScroller sample do I need to do?

I hope all is clear ;-)
Feel free to ask for more information if necessary...

Thanks in advance